# Get a number after a character in a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm making my own forums and I don't want any BB code on it, but instead my own,
so i've gotten [b][u][img] working etc.

But i'm having problems with [quote=1][/quote] where the number is the user id...

E.G lets say I quote someone

So once I submit my post: (The variable $post would be:)
'[quote=1] Quoted post :P[/quote]'

How would I then get the number out the string? (But not the wrong number -not a number in the quoted post)

(So I could then use str_replace() to replace with a table which makes it looked quoted)

?? :)

Comment: Ok i've got that working, one problem: ([quote] opens a table [/quote] closes it, however if someone quotes a thread -and forgets to [/quote] or something... the table (And thus the whole forum) breaks, how can I ensure a [/quote] follows a [quote]? (And only one [/quote])?? :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer. :) There are some things you have to take care of, for example that a quote could include line breaks or that there could be more than one quote in a post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very common to use regular expressions in order to implement BB-Codes. Of course you could use something like str_replace, but you will probably get some problems later.

Use the following pattern to make sure that the quote-tag gets also closed:

```
/\[quote=(\d+)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is
```

Now you should use preg_replace or preg_match to work with it.

For example:

```
echo preg_replace('/\[quote=(\d+)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is',
    '<b>\\1 wrote:</b> \\2',
    $input
);
```

Or:

```
$input = "text [quote=11]my quoted post
        abc[/quote]
        [quote=20]my quoted post 2[/quote]";


if(preg_match_all('/\[quote=(\d+)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/is', $input, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\[quote=([0-9]*)\]` and grab the captured string $1

```
$pattern = "{\[quote=([0-9]*)\](.*)\[\/quote\]}";
$subject = $post;
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);

//$matches[0] contains the whole string
//$matches[1] contains the id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
$post = '[quote=1] Quoted post :P[/quote]';
if (preg_match("/\\[quote=([\d]+)\\]/",$post,$matches)) {
  //echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true)."</pre>";
  $quote_user = $matches[1];
}
```